# How to dynamically update children of a div element in dash python

Tags: python, dynamic

My code is below and I have a series of dataframes in a dictionary called df_dct. All dataframes have a 'T' and 'Value' column along with some other classification columns. There may be other errors in the code below but what I'm most concerned about is that I can't access the children of the `html.Div(id=f'additional-dropdown-container-{key}')` elements after I try to populate them using this callback `@app.callback( Output(f'additional-dropdown-container-{key}', 'children'), [Input(f'multiple_line_column_optional-{key}', 'value')]`

print(dd_cont_child) should show a list of the filter elements which show up on the locally hosted app but instead show a list of None.
print(dd_containers) shows the container elements as expected but when I try and access the children of those elements they are not showing up. I need to access their elements as inputs for a callback later in the code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
# Your existing code to generate the layout dynamically based on the number of DataFrames
graphs_layout = [html.Div([
    html.H3(f"Graph for {key}"),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id=f'multiple_line_column_optional-{key}',
        options=[{'label': val, 'value': val} for val in df.columns if val not in ['T', 'Value']],
        multi=False,
        placeholder='Select value for multi lines...',
        style={'width': '50%'}
        ),
    html.Div(id=f'additional-dropdown-container-{key}'),
    dcc.Graph(id=f'line-plot-{key}'),])
    for key, df in df_dct.items()]

# Layout of the dashboard
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("Interactive Dashboard with Multiple Graphs"),
    html.Div(id='graphs-container', children=graphs_layout),
])

def create_update_filter_dropdowns_callback(key, df):

    @app.callback(
        Output(f'additional-dropdown-container-{key}', 'children'),
        [Input(f'multiple_line_column_optional-{key}', 'value')]
    )
    def update_filter_dropdowns(selected_column):
        dropdowns = []

        if selected_column is not None:
            for col in df.columns:
                if col not in ['T', 'Value', selected_column]:
                    dropdown_id = f'filter-{key}-{col}'
                    dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(
                        id=dropdown_id,
                        options=[{'label': val, 'value': val} for val in df[col].unique()],
                        multi=False,
                    )
                    dropdowns.append(dropdown)
        else:
            for col in df.columns:
                if col not in ['T', 'Value']:
                    dropdown_id = f'filter-{key}-{col}'
                    dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(
                        id=dropdown_id,
                        options=[{'label': val, 'value': val} for val in df[col].unique()],
                        multi=False,
                    )
                    dropdowns.append(dropdown)

        return dropdowns

for key, df in df_dct.items():
    create_update_filter_dropdowns_callback(key,df)

elements = [element.children for element in app.layout['graphs-container'].children if isinstance(element, html.Div)]
dd_containers = [dd for ele in elements for dd in ele if isinstance(dd, html.Div)]
dd_cont_child = [dd.children for dd in dd_containers]

print(dd_containers)
print(dd_cont_child)
```

I tried what was shown above and was expecting to be able to access the children elements of the containers but they were not showing up in the list.